# can´t set date in input type date

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i know, a similar question has been asked before, but i'm not understanding the answer/i feel it doesn't solve my problem.
I can´t set the date in my input type date.

```
export default function NewNoteModal() {
    return(
        <div id = "newNoteModal">
            {minimumSetDate()}
            <div id = "newNote-header">
                <h2>NoteKeeper</h2>
            </div>

            <form id = "newNote-content">
                <label htmlFor = "noteName">Note Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id = "noteName"></input>
                <br></br>
                {/* ---------------------- */}
                <label htmlFor="checkB-important">Important:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="important" value="important" id = "checkB-important"></input>
                <br></br>
                {/* ---------------------- */}
                <label htmlFor="remindDate">Remind me on:</label>
                <input type="date" name="remindDate" id = "remindDate"></input>
                <br></br>
                {/* ---------------------- */}
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

function minimumSetDate(){
    let today = new Date();

    let day = today.getDate(); // typeof = number
    let month = ('0' + (today.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2); // typeof = number
    let year = today.getFullYear(); // typeof = number

    let currentDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`; // typeof = string;
    console.log(typeof(currentDate), currentDate);
    document.getElementById("remindDate").value = currentDate;
}
```

the console gives "TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null";

however this in w3schools, works

```
document.getElementById("myDate").value = "2014-02-09";
```

Comment: Does your HTML element have the ID "remindDate" or "myDate"?

Comment: If you're getting the pointed error it's because the element you're trying to select in order to modify its "value" property doesn't exist.

Comment: Also note getDate and getMonth wont give you a zero padded value, so for like August you will get `7` and not `07` which will be an incorrect format for the value. You can use `padStart` to pad it eg `month.toString().padStart(2,'0')`

Comment: the id is "remindDate", but nevermind the answer by "Navnath Jadhav", was actually correct, apparently i had another problem. Its all ggod now.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let today = new Date();

let day = today.getDate(); // typeof = number
let month = ('0' + (today.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) // typeof = number
let year = today.getFullYear(); // typeof = number

let currentDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`; // typeof = string;
document.getElementById("remindDate").value = currentDate;
```

```html
<input type="date" id="remindDate">
```

Comment: Navnath Jadhav, thank you, your answer worked, i just happened to have another problem, which was solved by: "useEffect(() => {
  minimumSetDate();
 }, []);"